# How do I check if two HashMaps are equal in Dart?

Tags: dart

The default behavior for all Objects in Dart is to return true if and only if this object and other are the same object. How do I check if the values are the same?

```dart
import 'dart:collection' show HashMap;

final Map<int, String> planets1 = HashMap(); // Is a HashMap
final Map<int, String> planets2 = HashMap(); // Is another HashMap
planets1.addAll({5: 'Saturn', 6: 'Jupiter', 3: 'Earth', 4: 'Mars'});
planets2.addAll({5: 'Saturn', 6: 'Jupiter', 3: 'Earth', 4: 'Mars'});
print(planets1 == planets2); // prints false
```

Answer (score 1):

First import this package:

```
import 'package:collection/equality.dart';
```

and then print it out:

```
print(MapEquality().equals(planets1, planets1));
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
print(planets1.toString() === planets2.toString()); // prints true
```

Comment: The question is specifically about `HashMap` which does not guarantee anything about the ordering of entries. This may work, but it also may fail for maps with the same keys and values. And it can fail for maps with keys that have the same `toString`, but are otherwise not equal, like the integer `2` and the string `"2"`.

Answer (score 0):

```dart
import 'dart:collection';

import 'package:quiver/collection.dart';

void main() {
  final Map<int, String> planets1 = HashMap(); // Is a HashMap
  final Map<int, String> planets2 = HashMap(); // Is another HashMap
  planets1.addAll({5: 'Saturn', 6: 'Jupiter', 3: 'Earth', 4: 'Mars'});
  planets2.addAll({5: 'Saturn', 6: 'Jupiter', 3: 'Earth', 4: 'Mars'});
  print(mapsEqual(planets1, planets2)); // prints true
}
```